# default selection on custom Radio Button in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, radio-button

I want to implement radio buttons in my app 
I used https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/radiobutton (cocoa controls Radio Buttons) .
I want that one of them should always be selected by default. how can I achive this .

[image]

My Radio button code is as follows:

```
  RadioButton *radioButtonForDay = [[RadioButton alloc] initWithGroupId:@"first group" index:0 ];
RadioButton *radioButtonForWeek = [[RadioButton alloc] initWithGroupId:@"first group" index:1 ];
RadioButton *radioButtonForMonth = [[RadioButton alloc] initWithGroupId:@"first group" index:2 ];

radioButtonForDay.frame = CGRectMake(40,65,22,28);
radioButtonForWeek.frame = CGRectMake(130,65,22,28);
radioButtonForMonth.frame = CGRectMake(195,65,22,28);

[self.view addSubview:radioButtonForDay];
[self.view addSubview:radioButtonForWeek];
[self.view addSubview:radioButtonForMonth];

[RadioButton addObserverForGroupId:@"first group" observer:self];
```

RadioButton.m

`

## import "RadioButton.h"

@interface RadioButton()
-(void)defaultInit;
-(void)otherButtonSelected:(id)sender;
-(void)handleButtonTap:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation RadioButton

@synthesize groupId=_groupId;
@synthesize index=_index;

static const NSUInteger kRadioButtonWidth=22;
static const NSUInteger kRadioButtonHeight=22;

static NSMutableArray *rb_instances=nil;
static NSMutableDictionary *rb_observers=nil;

## pragma mark - Observer

+(void)addObserverForGroupId:(NSString*)groupId observer:(id)observer{
    if(!rb_observers){
        rb_observers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

```
if ([groupId length] > 0 && observer) {
    [rb_observers setObject:observer forKey:groupId];
    // Make it weak reference
    //[observer release];
}
```

}

## pragma mark - Manage Instances

+(void)registerInstance:(RadioButton*)radioButton{
    if(!rb_instances){
        rb_instances = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

```
[rb_instances addObject:radioButton];
// Make it weak reference
//[radioButton release];
```

}

## pragma mark - Class level handler

+(void)buttonSelected:(RadioButton*)radioButton{

```
// Notify observers
if (rb_observers) {
    id observer= [rb_observers objectForKey:radioButton.groupId];

    if(observer && [observer respondsToSelector:@selector(radioButtonSelectedAtIndex:inGroup:)]){
        [observer radioButtonSelectedAtIndex:radioButton.index inGroup:radioButton.groupId];
    }
}

// Unselect the other radio buttons
if (rb_instances) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [rb_instances count]; i++) {
        RadioButton *button = [rb_instances objectAtIndex:i];
        if (![button isEqual:radioButton] && [button.groupId isEqualToString:radioButton.groupId]) {
            [button otherButtonSelected:radioButton];
        }
    }
}
```

}

## pragma mark - Object Lifecycle

-(id)initWithGroupId:(NSString*)groupId index:(NSUInteger)index {
    self = [super init];

```
if (self) {
    _groupId = groupId;
    _index = index;
   // _selected = selected;

    [self defaultInit];
}
return  self;
```

}

- (void)dealloc
  {
  //[_groupId release];
  // [_button release];
  //  [super dealloc];
  }

## pragma mark - Tap handling

-(void)handleButtonTap:(id)sender{
    [_button setSelected:YES];
    [RadioButton buttonSelected:self];
}

-(void)otherButtonSelected:(id)sender{
    // Called when other radio button instance got selected
    if(_button.selected){
        [_button setSelected:NO];
    }
}

## pragma mark - RadioButton init

-(void)defaultInit{
    // Setup container view
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kRadioButtonWidth, kRadioButtonHeight);

```
// Customize UIButton
_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

_button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,kRadioButtonWidth, kRadioButtonHeight);
_button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO; 

[_button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioButton-Unselected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioButton-Selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[_button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleButtonTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self addSubview:_button];

[RadioButton registerInstance:self];
```

}

@end
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially set selected image to any of your button.

```
[yourBtn setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And according to your code just put `handleButtonTap` method in `RadioButton.h`

```
-(void)handleButtonTap:(id)sender;
```

and in `RadioButtonViewController.m` 
access the button which you want to select

Its for second button (i.e. RadioButton *rb2)

```
for (id subView in [rb2 subviews]) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [rb2 handleButtonTap:subView];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rajneesh071: I also had used this code in my app, but it is crashing and deallocating the object of UIViewController. Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

for default selection

```
        [btnR setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnG setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnUnCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnB setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnUnCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and  when you go to next view just check condition....

```
    UIImage* selectedImg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnCheck.png"]; //btnCheck.png your image name
    if (btnR.imageView.image == selectedImg  || btnG.imageView.image == selectedImg || btnB.imageView.image == selectedImg)
    {
             //One of them is selected
    }
    else {
       NSLog(@"Please Select At least One Color" );
    }
```